# NextJS stuck , can't navigate , can't refresh , can't hot reloading after a while

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, service-worker

My NextJS project was stuck after after sometime . Can't navigate . can't reload . The page function is still work , no lag . but I can't navigate any where . When I break the server I got those error . Pls help

```
Uncaught (in promise) no-response: no-response :: [{"url":"http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/login.js","error":{}}]
    at Object.handle (http://localhost:3000/workbox-a1b75552.js:1:16769)
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Cache.put() encountered a network error
```

[image: Error inspect]